# how to add year to persian date in sql server?

Tags: sql, sql-server

i have persiandate column in sql table ,i want update year of persiandate.persiandate is string like this `'1396/12/07'`
how to update persiandate from `'1396/12/07'` to `'1398/12/07'` base on +2 year default

Comment: A date is a date, regardless of where it is. Should always be stored as a date, then output as whatever format you want, usually base on where some front-end user has set their preferences. Where do you want to do this - in sql query, update statement, or what?

Comment: I'd consider storing regular dates (ISO 8601) in the table, and have views / functions to return/insert persian dates.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
DECLARE @DataSource TABLE
(
    [PersianDate] VARCHAR(12)
);

INSERT INTO @DataSource ([PersianDate])
VALUES ('1396/12/07');

UPDATE @DataSource
SET [PersianDate] = CAST(LEFT([PersianDate], 4) + 2 AS VARCHAR(4)) + RIGHT([PersianDate], 6);

SELECT [PersianDate]
FROM @DataSource;
```

For SQL Server 2012+, you can use:

```
CONCAT(LEFT([PersianDate], 4) + 2, RIGHT([PersianDate], 6))
```

Answer (score 0):

hi this code maybe help you

```
    select cast (floor  (( cast (substring  ('1396/12/07' ,6,2)as int ) 
+isnull(monthCount,0))/12 ) + cast (left ('1396/12/07' ,4)as int ) as varchar(4) )
      +'/'+   
RIGHT('00' + cast (substring  ('1396/12/07' ,6,2)as int ) ,2)
      +'/'+
      RIGHT('00' + CONVERT(VARCHAR,substring  ('1396/12/07' ,9,2) ), 2)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following query.

```
SELECT CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(YEAR,2,CONVERT(DATE, '1396/12/07', 120)),111)
```

Update Query.

```
UPDATE TABLE1 SET persiandate_Col=CONVERT(VARCHAR(10),DATEADD(YEAR,2,CONVERT(DATE, persiandate_Col, 120)),111)
```